# C# WPF How to modify the ComboBox's selected item's color?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am having trouble with the ComboBox's selected item color... By default, when you select an item from the ComboBox, it's Black. How do I change the color of the item to White? I cannot seem to modify it. What's the deal?

Comment: Have you tried using the `foreground` element to set the colour?

Comment: Well, they're white now, but when I drop down the menu, it's all white too, meaning, I can't see any item in the drop down menu. How can I set it to be Black or something?

Comment: google wpf combobox selected item color , you will find many answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case you can write this in XAML:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DropDowmItems}" Foreground="Red">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

In the case of item template, you need to modify that template.